# How to Implement Chainlink VRF into EIP2535 Standard Contract

Tags: solidity, chainlink, randomness, chainlink-vrf, chainlink-automation

I'm currently working on a smart contract that involves using Chainlink VRF (Verifiable Random Function) through a Diamond contract. My contract structure includes a `performUpkeep` function, which triggers periodically and calls `drawRandomNumbers()` to get random numbers for further processing.

Here's a simplified version of the contract:

```
contract Contract is
    Storage,
    ReentrancyGuard,
    UsingDiamondOwner,
    UserManager,
    AutomationCompatibleInterface
{

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        counter += 1;
        drawRandomNumbers(); // Issue arises when this function is added
    }

    function drawRandomNumbers() public {
        uint256 requestId = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator)
            .requestRandomWords(
                keyHash,
                s_subscriptionId,
                requestConfirmations,
                callbackGasLimit,
                numWords
            );
        lastRequestId = requestId;
    }

    function rawFulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 requestId,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) external {
        round += 1;
        // Here, I want to call drawLottery function with randomNumbers and update Diamond state variables
        // How can I achieve this considering drawRandomNumbers() is called from performUpkeep?
        drawLottery(randomWords);
        emit RequestFulfilled(round, randomWords, requestId);
    }
}
```

The issue arises when `drawRandomNumbers()` is added to the `performUpkeep()` function. The `rawFulfillRandomWords` function is triggered after the random numbers are received, but I'm unable to update Diamond state variables from `drawLottery` as it seems to be only callable from the Lottery contract.

I'd like to understand the best approach to achieve the following:

1. Call `drawRandomNumbers()` every time `performUpkeep` is triggered.
2. Wait for the random numbers to be fulfilled in `rawFulfillRandomWords`.
3. Call `drawLottery` with those random numbers.
4. Update Diamond state variables from `drawLottery`.

Any guidance or examples on how to structure this interaction between the Diamond contract and the Lottery contract would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** : Full code and Chainlink Upkeepers links are attached on
https://gist.github.com/MatheeshaMe/597655566650318342ee8d9a854f0cd5

**Note** : Full Public Repository for diamond Contracts and Lottery Facets  https://github.com/MatheeshaMe/EIP2535-proxy-Chainlink-VRF-Upkeepers

I also tried another simple contract as the `aavegotchi` contracts implemented VRF with main functions and tried it on the remix-  https://gist.github.com/MatheeshaMe/26c8f1bb39e88331d216191c5b42c4d9

in this version even though the contract has enough LINKs but I cannot call  `requestRandomness()` function always getting a gas estimation error, I also tried it on one of my diamond facets and getting the same error. (This is the method `aavegotchi` mentioned)
https://github.com/aavegotchi/aavegotchi-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Aavegotchi/facets/VRFFacet.sol

**Note**: I sent 30 LINK tokens to contract before requesting randomness. contract link on sepolia :
And approved link tokens to be spent on the vrfCoordinator address

here is the verified contract on sepolia https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x659294Bb0f8Ca71eE2Bf51641Bb0Fc92D2A98f06#

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you check your VRF Subscription to see the error information? If the request is detected by Chainlink VRF, you should be able to see if it is pending, failed or fulfillments on the page.

Comment: Now I am getting gas estimation error when i am trying to call ```requestRandomWords``` , Is it even possible  to implement chainlink VRF with EIP2535 ? 

```Error: execution reverted (unknown custom error) (action="estimateGas" ``` , I added diamond address as a consumer

These functions and ```pass the LINK address directly when inherit``` are working fine with a normal contract, I dont understand why this is not working at all

Comment: Is the fulfillment function you mentioned before working now? If you are not able to call the requestRamdomeWords, please check if the consumer address are in the VRF consumer and you assign the correct parameters when send a request.

Comment: There is nothing wrong as i can see, Also hardcoded all values in the contract ```0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c``` here is the keyhash. All these things are working when i assign this to a normal contract means non upgradable contract !!

Comment: @FrankKong I am checking another version of it, This is the gist URL for that, https://gist.github.com/MatheeshaMe/9423f6d08db33713f2b1e376eb4d9e1f , In this version Always i am getting an error called ```Callback gas limit set too low``` and I set the ```callbackGasLimit = 2500000``` as they mentioned on the documentation that is the maxGasLimit, My subscription has enough LINK also

Comment: The codes you shared in the gist cannot work because you did not override the function `fulfillRandomWords`. Your external function `rawFulfillRandomWords` will not be called by VRF because this is the function defined in `VRFConsumerBaseV2`.  The workflow is for CL VRF is the response to `VRFConsumerBaseV2` and then to the internal function `fulFillRandomWords` in your consumer contract. `Callback gas limit set too low` is because VRF cannot find the correct function to call.

Comment: Looks like you have many issues, please modify your question properly so that ppl can help. Maybe share your source code and subscription in the question, and list all issues you have.

Comment: Finally I got the response from the VRF request, It should be renamed by ```rawFulfillRandomness```  to ```rawFulfillRandomWords```  this, then i got the response back, Now I am facing that I cannot call the ```requestRandomWords``` from the diamond proxy, I have to call it manually with the contract that implemented. Even it cannot be called from the upkeeper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151090/discussion-between-praveenmatheesha-and-frank-kong).